# How to connect internally a Bloom docker container to a Neo4j docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, neo4j, bloom

Here is my problem : I cannot connect ****Internally**** (but externally it works) a bloom docker container to the neo4j docker container through the bolt port (7687).

***Summary***

I’m setting up a docker based project with :

- a Neo4j (GraphQL) as the database, in a docker container
- a Bloom server as the neo4j visualiser, that I’m including in an iframe (for lack of a better option now) in a react app
- a react app hosted on a node:14-alpine docker image.

Its all hosted in a AWS EC2 Linux instance.
All containers are on the same docker network, and when I ping them, either using their ip address of their docker name, or use curl to see if they can talk to each other, the connections all appear to work fine.

***What I tried***

- If I go to http://my.aws.ec.instance:7474   : I can see and use the Neo4j browser app, no problem.
- If I go to http://my.aws.ec.instance:7687 (the direct bolt connection), I get the message not «a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade» but it doesn’t appear to be a problem even though that where I’m supposed to get connected.
- From inside my bloom container, when I do ‘curl my.aws.ec.instance:7687, I get the same message.
- ‘db’ is my docker-compose service, ‘neo4j_c’ is the neo4j container name.
- When I do ‘curl db:7687' of 'curl 172.30.0.2:7687' (the ip of my neo4j container) or curl neo4j_c:7687 , i get the same message («a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade»).
  I then assume that theses connections are working the same way.

If I go to http://my.aws.ec.instance:8000, the bloom ‘app’ is up and running, but that is where I’m stuck.

To tell bloom where to find the database, I have to put the address in the ‘discovery.json’ file at / of the container, like this.

`"bolt": "bolt://my_db_address:7687"`

If I use the public address  "bolt": "bolt://my_ec2_instance_address:7687», it work and connect to the neo4j database container, but externally, which is definitely not what I want.

After trying to connect ‘internally’, using either the container IP address, or its name, I would just not connect, and I just can’t figure out why.
I tried :

```
"bolt": "bolt://db:7687"
"bolt": "bolt://neo4j_c:7687"
"bolt": "bolt://172.30.0.2:7687"
```

and many more combinaisons, with and without ports number, protocals etc... the only one working being :

```
"bolt": "bolt://my_aws_ec2_public_instance:7687"
```

but I'm can't work with that, there are on the same network and should connect locally.

****Can you guys help me out ? I probably set up something wrong...
Please ask me for any other informations you might need.****

I hope I made it clear enough. Thanks in advance for any contribution.

***Additional informations***

Docker version 19.03.6-ce, build 369ce74.

docker-compose version 1.27.0, build 980ec85b

the docker-compose file :

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: neo4j_c
    image: neo4j:4.1.1-enterprise
    environment:
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
    ports:
      - 7473:7473
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/data:/data
    networks:
      - ggnet

  bloom:
    container_name: bloom_c
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: bloom_dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./bloom:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - ggnet

networks:
  ggnet:
    name: ggnet_n
    driver: bridge
```

And the simple bloom dockerfile :

```
FROM nginx

COPY ./bloom/discovery.json /
```

bloom nginx container default.conf :

```
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    listen       7687;  #JUST ADDED THAT but it didn't change anything from previous tests..
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```

bloom nginx container nginx.conf :

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt you use the docker compose service name as url?

Comment: I tried that, either with the name of the service ('db' in my case) and with the name of the container ('neo4j_c'), and it doesn't work, even though when I ping or telnet on the right ports using theses, it works.